# Gradient descent in linear regression goes wrong

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I actually want to use a linear model to fit a set of 'sin' data, but it turns out the loss function goes larger during each iteration. Is there any problem with my code below ? (gradient descent method)

Here is my code in Matlab

```
m=20;
rate = 0.1;
x = linspace(0,2*pi,20);
x = [ones(1,length(x));x]
y = sin(x);
w = rand(1,2);
for i=1:500
    h = w*x;
    loss = sum((h-y).^2)/m/2 
    total_loss = [total_loss loss];
    **gradient = (h-y)*x'./m ;**
    w = w - rate.*gradient;
end
```

Here is the data I want to fit
[image: y=sin(x)]

Comment: Please improve your code. As it is, it does not run because m, rate, total_loss are not defined. Maybe you can even make it a bit shorter and more elegant along the way. Just include only the minimum necessary to see the problem.

Comment: Doing linear regression (i.e. slope and intercept) on sinusoidal data will probably not give you the right results.  If you want to fit that curve, you will probably need to add higher order terms (2nd order, 3rd order, etc.).  I will probably tell you now that you will not get accurate results.

Comment: Also please define all variables that were not previously defined: `m`, `rate`, `total_loss`.  My guess is that `total_loss` is an empty array that you are concatenating the loss function values for each iteration and `m` is the total number of desired points... so `20` in your case.  `rate` is something ad-hoc that depends on the data, so if you can show us what value of `rate` you're using, that will help.

Comment: I just update my question. Note that m, rate and all relative variables are all defined in my original script. That's not the problem of bug in the code but algorithm I suppose.

Comment: @JohnGreen - There isn't a problem.  In fact when I run your code, it converges but the loss term is relatively large... well, I get 0.1157.  If you want to fit sinusoidal data, you need to include higher order terms.  I'll write a post.

Comment: Actually I was trying to represent a over-fitting problem by increasing the  polynomial order step by step. When trying zero order (h=w), I can actually train a straight line(y=0) with very low error(0.27). But after I increase the order set(h = w0 + w1*x), the gradient doesn't appear to be reasonable.

Comment: @JohnGreen - Yeah you need to increase the number of terms you're representing your curve.  Representing sinusoidal data with only a straight line will most definitely give you high errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot @rayryeng, I just run the code on my own laptop, it actually converges. The problem was on the former code I type on the PC in my lab.

Comment: @JohnGreen - That's really weird!  Ok no worries.  I'm almost done here.

Comment: @rayryeng Found the problem!! I set 'rate' to be 0.2 on the previous version of code which made the loss term keep increasing.. Maybe the step size is too large to miss a local optima.

Comment: @JohnGreen - That makes sense!  Make sure the rate isn't too large or you will definitely miss the optima.

Comment: @JohnGreen - I've added a graph on top of my post.  Thanks for accepting btw :)

Comment: @JohnGreen - I've also noticed you're a new user.  Welcome to StackOverflow!  I see you've already gotten your [hands dirty](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4649763/john-green?tab=reputation) :).

Comment: Yes indeed, I just signed up a few hours ago and have noticed StackOverflow is an amazing place. Thanks for your welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a problem with your code.  With your current framework, if you can define data in the form of `y = m*x + b`, then this code is more than adequate.  I actually ran it through a few tests where I define an equation of the line and add some Gaussian random noise to it (amplitude = 0.1, mean = 0, std. dev = 1).

However, one problem I will mention to you is that if you take a look at your sinusoidal data, you define a domain between `[0,2*pi]`.  As you can see, you have multiple `x` values that get mapped to the same `y` value but of different magnitude.  For example, at `x = pi/2` we get 1 but at `x = -3*pi/2` we get -1.  This high variability will not bode well with linear regression, and so one suggestion I have is to restrict your domain... so something like `[0, pi]`.  Another reason why it probably doesn't converge is the learning rate you chose is too high.  I'd set it to something low like `0.01`.  As you mentioned in your comments, you already figured that out!

However, if you want to fit non-linear data using linear regression, you're going to have to include higher order terms to account for the variability.  As such, try including second order and/or third order terms.  This can simply be done by modifying your `x` matrix like so:

```
x = [ones(1,length(x)); x; x.^2; x.^3];
```

If you recall, the hypothesis function can be represented as a summation of linear terms:

```
h(x) = theta0 + theta1*x1 + theta2*x2 + ... + thetan*xn
```

In our case, each `theta` term would build a higher order term of our polynomial.  `x2` would be `x^2` and `x3` would be `x^3`.  Therefore, we can still use the definition of gradient descent for linear regression here.

I'm also going to control the random generation seed (via `rng`) so that you can produce the same results I have gotten:

```
clear all; 
close all;
rng(123123);
total_loss = [];
m = 20;
x = linspace(0,pi,m); %// Change
y = sin(x);
w = rand(1,4); %// Change
rate = 0.01; %// Change
x = [ones(1,length(x)); x; x.^2; x.^3]; %// Change - Second and third order terms
for i=1:500
    h = w*x;
    loss = sum((h-y).^2)/m/2;
    total_loss = [total_loss loss];
    % gradient is now in a different expression
    gradient = (h-y)*x'./m ; % sum all in each iteration, it's a batch gradient
    w = w - rate.*gradient;
end
```

If we try this, we get for `w` (your parameters):

```
>> format long g;
>> w


w =

  Columns 1 through 3

         0.128369521905694         0.819533906064327       -0.0944622478526915

  Column 4

       -0.0596638117151464
```

My final loss after this point is:

```
loss =

       0.00154350916582836
```

This means that our equation of the line is:

```
y = 0.12 + 0.819x - 0.094x^2 - 0.059x^3
```

If we plot this equation of the line with your sinusoidal data, this is what we get:

```
xval = x(2,:);
plot(xval, y, xval, polyval(fliplr(w), xval))
legend('Original', 'Fitted');
```

[image]